# typeorm get repository from name

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

To create REST API for any entity.
Can I use table name instead of `Entity` for queryBuilder?

```js
const repository = getRepository("Table_Name"); // instead of Entity, I want use string `Any Table name`.
repository.createQueryBuilder( ...  )
    .leftJoin(['TableA', 'TableB'])
    .orderBy("TableA.name")
    .offset(5)
    .limit(10);
```

Comment: You mean something like `userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to find the correct entity name given that you already know the name of the database table.

Assuming you have only one database to connect to, you can do something like this:

```js
const tableName = "Table_Name";
const entityMetadata = getConnection().entityMetadatas.find((metadata) => metadata.tableName === tableName);
const repository = getRepository(entityMetadata.name);
```

For your `TableA` and `TableB`, I guess you can follow the same logic.

Comment: thanks, `getRepository("TableName")` is enoug for my answer. if possible, please update with only  "getRepository("TableName")"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow. In my answer, I am trying to show you how to get the entity's name so that you can pass it inside `getRepository` because it does not take the table name as a parameter

Comment: by the way, this is my answer, only I don't need `entityMetadata = getConnection().entityMetadatas.find((metadata) => metadata.tableName === tableName);`

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. If you didn't need it, how are you going to pass the name of the entity to `getRepository` function? Maybe you can update my answer with the solution you have :-)